# java.lang.AbstractMethod Error when build metabase

Tags: java, clojure, metabase

excute command

> "./bin/build" in metabase-0.32.8

java info:

> java version "11.0.3" 2019-04-16 LTS
>
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.3+12-LTS)
>
> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.3+12-LTS, mixed mode)

system info:

> Distributor ID: Ubuntu
>
> Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
>
> Release:        16.04
>
> Codename:       xenial

```sh
This is almost certainly a mistake; for details see
https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/doc/FAQ.md
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class leiningen.core.main$insecure_http_abort$reify__6678 does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method abstract removeTransferListener(Lorg/apache/maven/wagon/events/TransferListener;)V of interface org.apache.maven.wagon.Wagon.
        at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter.execute(WagonTransporter.java:440)
        at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter.get(WagonTransporter.java:413)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$GetTaskRunner.runTask(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:456)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:359)
        at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:75)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$DirectExecutor.execute(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:590)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.get(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:258)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:498)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:399)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:224)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:201)
        at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:261)
        at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:192)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.resolveCachedArtifactDescriptor(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:539)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.getArtifactDescriptorResult(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:522)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:411)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:365)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.process(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:353)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.doRecurse(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:507)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:460)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:365)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.process(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:353)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:256)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:307)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeMatchingMethod(Reflector.java:167)
        at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeInstanceMethod(Reflector.java:102)
        at cemerick.pomegranate.aether$resolve_dependencies_STAR_.invokeStatic(aether.clj:806)
        at cemerick.pomegranate.aether$resolve_dependencies_STAR_.doInvoke(aether.clj:707)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
        at clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:665)
        at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:660)
        at cemerick.pomegranate.aether$resolve_dependencies.invokeStatic(aether.clj:815)
        at cemerick.pomegranate.aether$resolve_dependencies.doInvoke(aether.clj:809)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:2793)
        at leiningen.core.classpath$get_dependencies_STAR_.invokeStatic(classpath.clj:274)
        at leiningen.core.classpath$get_dependencies_STAR_.invoke(classpath.clj:266)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:165)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:144)
        at clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:665)
        at clojure.core$memoize$fn__6862.doInvoke(core.clj:6353)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:457)
        at leiningen.core.classpath$get_dependencies$fn__6105.invoke(classpath.clj:333)
        at leiningen.core.classpath$get_dependencies.invokeStatic(classpath.clj:331)
        at leiningen.core.classpath$get_dependencies.doInvoke(classpath.clj:325)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:445)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:160)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:132)
        at clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:671)
        at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:660)
        at leiningen.core.classpath$resolve_managed_dependencies.invokeStatic(classpath.clj:444)
        at leiningen.core.classpath$resolve_managed_dependencies.doInvoke(classpath.clj:431)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:445)
        at leiningen.core.eval$prep.invokeStatic(eval.clj:85)
        at leiningen.core.eval$prep.invoke(eval.clj:73)
        at leiningen.jar$build_jar.invokeStatic(jar.clj:286)
        at leiningen.jar$build_jar.invoke(jar.clj:283)
        at leiningen.jar$main_jar.invokeStatic(jar.clj:295)
        at leiningen.jar$main_jar.invoke(jar.clj:291)
        at leiningen.jar$jar.invokeStatic(jar.clj:346)
        at leiningen.jar$jar.invoke(jar.clj:328)
        at leiningen.jar$jar.invokeStatic(jar.clj:348)
        at leiningen.jar$jar.invoke(jar.clj:328)
        at leiningen.install$install.invokeStatic(install.clj:21)
        at leiningen.install$install.invoke(install.clj:12)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:154)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:144)
        at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:705)
        at clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:667)
        at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:660)
        at leiningen.core.main$partial_task$fn__6592.doInvoke(main.clj:284)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:410)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:154)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:132)
        at clojure.lang.AFunction$1.doInvoke(AFunction.java:31)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
        at clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:667)
        at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:660)
        at leiningen.core.main$apply_task.invokeStatic(main.clj:334)
        at leiningen.core.main$apply_task.invoke(main.clj:320)
        at lein_environ.plugin$write_env_to_file.invokeStatic(plugin.clj:29)
        at lein_environ.plugin$write_env_to_file.invoke(plugin.clj:27)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:165)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:144)
        at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:705)
        at clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:667)
        at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:660)
        at robert.hooke$compose_hooks$fn__10419.doInvoke(hooke.clj:40)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
        at clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:665)
        at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:660)
        at robert.hooke$run_hooks.invokeStatic(hooke.clj:46)
        at robert.hooke$run_hooks.invoke(hooke.clj:45)
        at robert.hooke$prepare_for_hooks$fn__10424$fn__10425.doInvoke(hooke.clj:54)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
        at clojure.lang.AFunction$1.doInvoke(AFunction.java:31)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:436)
        at leiningen.with_profile$with_profiles_STAR_.invokeStatic(with_profile.clj:14)
        at leiningen.with_profile$with_profiles_STAR_.invoke(with_profile.clj:8)
        at leiningen.with_profile$apply_task_with_profiles.invokeStatic(with_profile.clj:53)
        at leiningen.with_profile$apply_task_with_profiles.invoke(with_profile.clj:45)
        at leiningen.with_profile$with_profile$fn__10482.invoke(with_profile.clj:85)
        at clojure.core$mapv$fn__8430.invoke(core.clj:6912)
        at clojure.core.protocols$fn__8144.invokeStatic(protocols.clj:168)
        at clojure.core.protocols$fn__8144.invoke(protocols.clj:124)
        at clojure.core.protocols$fn__8099$G__8094__8108.invoke(protocols.clj:19)
        at clojure.core.protocols$seq_reduce.invokeStatic(protocols.clj:31)
        at clojure.core.protocols$fn__8131.invokeStatic(protocols.clj:75)
        at clojure.core.protocols$fn__8131.invoke(protocols.clj:75)
        at clojure.core.protocols$fn__8073$G__8068__8086.invoke(protocols.clj:13)
        at clojure.core$reduce.invokeStatic(core.clj:6828)
        at clojure.core$mapv.invokeStatic(core.clj:6903)
        at clojure.core$mapv.invoke(core.clj:6903)
        at leiningen.with_profile$with_profile.invokeStatic(with_profile.clj:85)
        at leiningen.with_profile$with_profile.doInvoke(with_profile.clj:63)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:445)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:160)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:132)
        at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:705)
        at clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:667)
        at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:660)
        at leiningen.core.main$partial_task$fn__6592.doInvoke(main.clj:284)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:410)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:154)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:132)
        at clojure.lang.AFunction$1.doInvoke(AFunction.java:31)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
        at clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:667)
        at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:660)
        at leiningen.core.main$apply_task.invokeStatic(main.clj:334)
        at leiningen.core.main$apply_task.invoke(main.clj:320)
        at lein_environ.plugin$write_env_to_file.invokeStatic(plugin.clj:29)
        at lein_environ.plugin$write_env_to_file.invoke(plugin.clj:27)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:165)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:144)
        at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:705)
        at clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:667)
        at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:660)
        at robert.hooke$compose_hooks$fn__10419.doInvoke(hooke.clj:40)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
        at clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:665)
        at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:660)
        at robert.hooke$run_hooks.invokeStatic(hooke.clj:46)
        at robert.hooke$run_hooks.invoke(hooke.clj:45)
        at robert.hooke$prepare_for_hooks$fn__10424$fn__10425.doInvoke(hooke.clj:54)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
        at clojure.lang.AFunction$1.doInvoke(AFunction.java:31)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:436)
        at leiningen.with_profile$with_profiles_STAR_.invokeStatic(with_profile.clj:14)
        at leiningen.with_profile$with_profiles_STAR_.invoke(with_profile.clj:8)
        at leiningen.with_profile$apply_task_with_profiles.invokeStatic(with_profile.clj:53)
        at leiningen.with_profile$apply_task_with_profiles.invoke(with_profile.clj:45)
        at leiningen.with_profile$with_profile$fn__10482.invoke(with_profile.clj:85)
        at clojure.core$mapv$fn__8430.invoke(core.clj:6912)
        at clojure.core.protocols$fn__8144.invokeStatic(protocols.clj:168)
        at clojure.core.protocols$fn__8144.invoke(protocols.clj:124)
        at clojure.core.protocols$fn__8099$G__8094__8108.invoke(protocols.clj:19)
        at clojure.core.protocols$seq_reduce.invokeStatic(protocols.clj:31)
        at clojure.core.protocols$fn__8131.invokeStatic(protocols.clj:75)
        at clojure.core.protocols$fn__8131.invoke(protocols.clj:75)
        at clojure.core.protocols$fn__8073$G__8068__8086.invoke(protocols.clj:13)
        at clojure.core$reduce.invokeStatic(core.clj:6828)
        at clojure.core$mapv.invokeStatic(core.clj:6903)
        at clojure.core$mapv.invoke(core.clj:6903)
        at leiningen.with_profile$with_profile.invokeStatic(with_profile.clj:85)
        at leiningen.with_profile$with_profile.doInvoke(with_profile.clj:63)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:445)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:160)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:132)
        at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:705)
        at clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:667)
        at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:660)
        at leiningen.core.main$partial_task$fn__6592.doInvoke(main.clj:284)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:410)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:154)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:132)
        at clojure.lang.AFunction$1.doInvoke(AFunction.java:31)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
        at clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:667)
        at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:660)
        at leiningen.core.main$apply_task.invokeStatic(main.clj:334)
        at leiningen.core.main$apply_task.invoke(main.clj:320)
        at lein_environ.plugin$write_env_to_file.invokeStatic(plugin.clj:29)
        at lein_environ.plugin$write_env_to_file.invoke(plugin.clj:27)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:165)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:144)
        at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:705)
        at clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:667)
        at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:660)
        at robert.hooke$compose_hooks$fn__10419.doInvoke(hooke.clj:40)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
        at clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:665)
        at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:660)
        at robert.hooke$run_hooks.invokeStatic(hooke.clj:46)
        at robert.hooke$run_hooks.invoke(hooke.clj:45)
        at robert.hooke$prepare_for_hooks$fn__10424$fn__10425.doInvoke(hooke.clj:54)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
        at clojure.lang.AFunction$1.doInvoke(AFunction.java:31)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:436)
        at leiningen.core.main$resolve_and_apply.invokeStatic(main.clj:343)
        at leiningen.core.main$resolve_and_apply.invoke(main.clj:336)
        at leiningen.core.main$_main$fn__6681.invoke(main.clj:452)
        at leiningen.core.main$_main.invokeStatic(main.clj:442)
        at leiningen.core.main$_main.doInvoke(main.clj:439)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
        at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:705)
        at clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:665)
        at clojure.main$main_opt.invokeStatic(main.clj:491)
        at clojure.main$main_opt.invoke(main.clj:487)
        at clojure.main$main.invokeStatic(main.clj:598)
        at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:561)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
        at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:705)
        at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is related to the issue [lein repl (2.8.2) throws an exception on Ubuntu 18.04 and 16.04](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/issues/2497).

If you use the latest version of Leiningen you should be fine.

Remove old install: `rm  ~/bin/lein`

Install:

> Leiningen and Clojure require Java. OpenJDK version 8 is recommended at this time.
>
> - Download the [`lein` script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/technomancy/leiningen/stable/bin/lein) (or on Windows lein.bat)
>
>   - Place it on your $PATH where your shell can find it (eg. `~/bin`)
>   - Set it to be executable (`chmod a+x ~/bin/lein`)
>   - Run it (`lein`) and it will download the self-install package

Source: https://leiningen.org/

Comment: the version of Leiningen 2.9.1